# Difference between update_user_meta and update_user_option

Tags: users, user-meta

Can anyone explain what is the difference between `update_user_meta` and `update_user_option` and in which scenarios the both can be used?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In layman terms there is no major difference! `update_user_option()` uses `update_user_meta()` internally. The only difference is `update_user_option()` prefix the option name with database table prefix + blog ID if you are in multisite and just table prefix if you are in single site installation.

Take a look at the code of `update_user_option()`

```
/**
 * Update user option with global blog capability.
 *
 * User options are just like user metadata except that they have support for
 * global blog options. If the 'global' parameter is false, which it is by default
 * it will prepend the WordPress table prefix to the option name.
 *
 * Deletes the user option if $newvalue is empty.
 *
 * @since 2.0.0
 *
 * @global wpdb $wpdb WordPress database abstraction object.
 *
 * @param int    $user_id     User ID.
 * @param string $option_name User option name.
 * @param mixed  $newvalue    User option value.
 * @param bool   $global      Optional. Whether option name is global or blog specific.
 *                            Default false (blog specific).
 * @return int|bool User meta ID if the option didn't exist, true on successful update,
 *                  false on failure.
 */
function update_user_option( $user_id, $option_name, $newvalue, $global = false ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( !$global )
        $option_name = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . $option_name;

    return update_user_meta( $user_id, $option_name, $newvalue );
}
```

Your option name is prefixed with table prefix + blog ID (Only when ID is other than 1 and 0).

If you set the last parameter `$global` to `true` it has no difference with `update_user_meta()`.

**Purpose of `update_user_option()` function**

Unlike other tables, WordPress does not create separate table for usermeta for each site. It saves user information in one usermeta table for all of the blogs (in multisite). It just prefix the key name for each site with `blog prefix` e.g. for blog ID 4 `wp_capabilities` is stored as `wp_4_capabilities`.

So whatever information you will save using `update_user_option()`, for example `key_name_abc` will become `wp_key_name_abc` for main site in multisite or in single site installation. In future if you convert your single site to multisite the information will be available only in main site.

Use this function when you think some information is depended on site + user as well. Not like name, email etc because these information belongs to user and site independent.

Answer (score 7):

Both write their data in the “usermeta” table. User options stored in the usermeta table retain the wordpress table prefix e.g. wp_ whereas the user meta also stored in the usermeta table doesn't.

User options support blog-specific options, useful in multisite. The user meta is based on the user id specific meta data like profile information.

The parameters are quite different in fact. User option has $user_id, $option_name, $newvalue, $global and user meta has $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value.

Here are some values for both options and user usermeta.

Options

- wp_user_level
- wp_user-settings
- wp_capabilities
- wp_user-settings-time

User

- first_name
- last_name
- nickname
- rich_editing
- show_admin_bar_front
- admin_color

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_option#Parameters

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta#Parameters

The codex pages examples provide real world use.

Comment: Can you be clearer about where these are stored? Your first sentence suggests they're stored in the same place, but your second implies they aren't, perhaps an explicit example would be better? Keep in mind that answers should be self contained, so they still make sense after linkrot sets in. The codex is also poorly maintained and being replaced by the devhub

Comment: @TomJNowell these can be found in wp-includes/user.php - you will find values for both meta and options in the usermeta table. I'll edit my answer lol